# Is $\operatorname{null}(B) \subset \operatorname{null}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ and $B$ are two symmetric and PSD matrices. Also,

$B = A + ee^T$.

How can one prove that $\operatorname{null}(B) \subset \operatorname{null}(A)$?

Comment: Suppose $x \in \operatorname{null}(B)$, i.e., $Bx = 0$. What can you prove about $Ax$?

Comment: We somehow have to prove that x satisfies Ax = 0, and thereby prove that x belongs to null(A) too?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** look at $x^tBx=x^tAx+x^tee^tx$, where $x$ is such that $Bx=0$.